# Loading a Model with weights and optimizers without creating an instance in PyTorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert

I recently downloaded [Camembert Model](https://camembert-model.fr/) to fine-tune it for my purpose.

Upon unzipping the file the contents are:
[image]

Upon loading the `model.pt` file using pytorch:

```
import torch
model = torch.load(model_saved_at)
```

I saw that `model` was in OrderedDict format containing the following keys:

```
args
model
optimizer_history
extra_state
last_optimizer_state
```

As the name suggests most of them are `OrderedKeys` themselves with the exception of `args` which belongs to a class `argsparse.Namespace`. Using `vars()` we can see `args` only contains some hyperparameters and values which are to be passed from the command-line.

`model["model"]` contains the weights which I want to load and use as my base model.
A small part of it is as shown below:

```
for ans in model["model"].keys():
    try:
        print(ans, "\t" ,model["model"][ans].size())
    except:
        print(ans, type(ans))
```

```
decoder.sentence_encoder.embed_tokens.weight     torch.Size([32005, 768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.embed_positions.weight      torch.Size([514, 768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_weight   torch.Size([2304, 768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_bias     torch.Size([2304])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj.weight      torch.Size([768, 768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj.bias    torch.Size([768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn_layer_norm.weight    torch.Size([768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.self_attn_layer_norm.bias      torch.Size([768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.fc1.weight     torch.Size([3072, 768])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.fc1.bias   torch.Size([3072])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.fc2.weight     torch.Size([768, 3072])
decoder.sentence_encoder.layers.0.fc2.bias   torch.Size([768])
```

However, I cannot use `load_state_dict()` since I have no instance of this class. How am I suppose to load the weights and optimization parameters without creating an instance? I thought of using `sentence.bpe.model` but they are for tokenization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using huggingface transformer for fine tuning which is really popular, here is a code sample:

```
import transformers
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model,self).__init__()
        self.Bert = transformers.CamemBertModel.from_pretrained('camembert-base')
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(768,1)

        nn.init.normal_(self.fc0.weight,std= 0.1)
        nn.init.normal_(self.fc0.bias ,0.)
        
    def forward(self,input_ids,attention_mask):
        hid= self.Bert(input_ids,attention_mask = attention_mask)
        hid= hid[0][:,0]
        x = self.fc0(hid)
        return x
```

You can change your last layer as you need.It is just a sample. It will load the pretrained weights from huggingface.You need not provide it.You can install transformers by the following line in terminal.

```
pip3 install transformers
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I downloaded this seperately just to avoid using huggingface, it definitely would be easy but it would also restrict a lot of what I can and cannot do.

Comment: without the class file,which you won't probably have, you cannot optimize the camembert layer.All you can do is use it as a encoder layer,extract features and train your last layers which is similar as above.Rather in above you can optimizer camembert as well

Comment: Is there any way to just load the initial model and not optimize those and only optimize the layers that I would be adding after these?

Comment: Yes. Just like the code i have provided. Instead of transform layer use your model layer to get output and send them to your layers

Comment: Could you make an edit showing how would one go on from first layer to the last?